# ENONT: no such file or directory - '\debug\src'

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have finnaly completed my electronJS application and was ready to compile it using "Electron-Compiler" all went smootly until i ran into an error saying this

```
Packaging app for platform win32 x64 using electron v11.0.3
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\Software\oneDrive\file\Code\electronJS\File Saver\file-saver old design\node_modules\stylus\node_modules\debug\src'
```

i have searched about and havn't found anything that has helped me with this error.